# Is it possible to have multi label widget ? for example like tabular column ? in Tkinter Python?

Tags: python-2.7, tkinter

Is it possible to create a multi label widget like a tabular column ? For, example as shown in the snapshot attached ?

[image]

Kindly let me know or provide some comments if there is any option to create widgets with multi label option ?

Thanks !

Comment: Well you 2nd options is doable with a frame and 2 labels like you mentioned. The one with the diagonal line thought. That one takes a little bit more. You would end up using a frame and a canvas and then draw the line and labels on the canvas. That said you will need to provide a code attempt. Most people here will not just write the code for you.

Comment: @Mike-SMT: Oh, I tried the 2nd one already. But I was just wondering if there was any way using which I can code to generate a widget. I was jst looking for a clue so that I can search around and code using that method.

Comment: You can write a class that inherits from a widget and add features to it however I have not done this very often so I am not sure how well this would work on labels. I have done it for Frames only. That said to get something that looks like your first option I am thinking you will have to use a canvas and the draw line method as well as adding 2 small labels to the canvas to create something like option one.

Comment: @Mike-SMT : Got it. Thanks for the comments. Appreciate that !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no built-in way to do that, but it's relatively easy to write your own using a canvas. For example, put one label in the upper-right corner and the other in the lower-left. Then, draw a line from upper-left to lower-right.

Example:

```
import tkinter as tk

class CustomLabel(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, label1, label2, **kwargs):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent, **kwargs)

        self.canvas = tk.Canvas(self, borderwidth=0, highlightthickness=0, background=self.cget("background"))
        self.canvas.pack(fill="both", expand=True)

        l1 = tk.Label(self.canvas, text=label1, background=self.cget("background"))
        l2 = tk.Label(self.canvas, text=label2, background=self.cget("background"))

        l1.place(relx=.75, rely=.25, anchor="c")
        l2.place(relx=.25, rely=.75, anchor="c")

        # arrange for the line to be redrawn whenever the canvas
        # changes size
        self.canvas.bind("<Configure>", self.handle_configure)

        # set the default size to be relative to the requested size
        # of the labels plus some margin
        width  = l1.winfo_reqwidth()  + l2.winfo_reqwidth() + 4
        height = l1.winfo_reqheight() + l2.winfo_reqheight() + 4
        self.canvas.configure(width=width, height=height)

    def handle_configure(self, event):
        self.canvas.delete("line")
        self.canvas.create_line(0,0,event.width, event.height, tags=("line",))
```

Example usage:

```
root = tk.Tk()

colors = ("SteelBlue4", "SteelBlue3", "SkyBlue1")
for row in range(3):
    for column in range(4):
        if row == 0 and column == 0:
            widget = CustomLabel(root, "Place", "Name", background=colors[row])
        else:
            widget = tk.Label(root, text="", background=colors[row])
        widget.grid(row=row, column=column, sticky="nsew", padx=1, pady=1)

for row in range(3):
    root.grid_rowconfigure(row, uniform="row")

for column in range(4):
    root.grid_columnconfigure(column, uniform="column")
```

Screenshot:

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Say using the above function/process have placed like 20 or 30 different Combobox. So wheneer the binded function to the combobox gets triggered while selecting a value, is it possible to get the location [i.e. the row and the column] value for a particular widget placed in the grid ? Is there any system function but into it ?